# naive unit checking via strong typing and operator overloading

Tags: ada

I was reading about [strong typing in Ada](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-ada/chapters/strongly_typed_language.html#strong-typing) focused on [units checking](https://gmpreussner.com/research/dimensional-analysis-in-programming-languages#ada), and decided to test the naive approach out myself:

```
procedure Example is
  type Meters is new Float;
  type Meters_Squared is new Float; 
  function "*" (Left, Right : Meters) return Meters_Squared is
  begin
    return Meters_Squared(Float(Left)*Float(Right));
  end;
  len_a : Meters := 10.0;
  len_b : Meters := 15.0;
  surface : Meters_Squared;
  len_sum : Meters;
begin
  len_sum := len_a + len_b; -- ok
  surface := len_a * len_b; -- ok
  len_sum := len_a * len_b; -- invalid
end Example;
```

Now I know that this is not actually practical approach, I'm trying this just as a learning experience. And based on my attempts so far, I must be missing something, because when I try to compile the example listed above, I get no errors:

```
$ make example
gcc -c example.adb
gnatmake example.adb
gnatbind -x example.ali
gnatlink example.ali
```

While when I drop the function definition overloading the multiplication operator, it fails as expected:

```
$ make example
gcc -c example.adb
example.adb:14:20: expected type "Meters_Squared" defined at line 3
example.adb:14:20: found type "Meters" defined at line 2
make: *** [Makefile:6: example] Error 1
```

With this in mind, I don't understand how, with the multiplication operator overloading, the compiler could be ok with `surface := len_a * len_b` and `len_sum := len_a * len_b` at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `"*"` overloading is just that; `Meters` inherits

```
function "*" (Left, Right: Meters) return Meters;
```

from `Float`.

What you can do is suppress that inherited function:

```
function "*" (Left, Right: Meters) return Meters
is abstract;
```

---

In this case, marking the undesired function `abstract` removes it from consideration for overload resolution: in [ARM 6.4(8)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-6-4.html#p8) we have

> ... The name or prefix shall not resolve to denote an abstract subprogram unless it is also a dispatching subprogram.

and `Meters` isn’t a tagged type, so `"*"` isn’t dispatching.

You can also declare a non-overloaded subprogram `abstract`:

```
function "and" (Left, Right : Meters) return Meters
is abstract;
```

to which GNAT says `cannot call abstract subprogram "and"`, because of ARM [3.9.3(7)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-9-3.html#p7).

Comment: The Annotated Ada Reference Manual says, in [3.9.3](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/aarm12_w_tc1/html/AA-3-9-3.html): {AI95-00310-01} In Ada 2005, abstract primitive subprograms of an untagged type may be used to “undefine” an operation.

Comment: @egilhh, that’s an old AI, which might explain why it only contains modifications to ARM 6.4(8) and no AARM modifications at all.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. When I suppressed the inherited function, it now fails as expected. That said the error reported by the compiler is little confusing, as it notes: `example.adb:16:20: expected type "Meters" defined at line 2` and `example.adb:16:20: found type "Meters" defined at line 2`.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? here, the second line says `found type "Meters_Squared" defined at line 3`. (GNAT CE 2020, FSF GCC 11.0.1)

Comment: I'm using `gcc-gnat-10.2.1` .